# wix installer: how to handle multiple levels of quotes

Tags: wix

I'm trying to wrap some executables (which I cannot redesign) into separate MSI files and execute the executable with arguments that may contain quotes.

So my CustomAction looks something like:

```
<CustomAction Id="PAYLOAD_EXE" FileKey="FILE1.EXE" ExeCommand="/VERYSILENT /PARAM=&quot;-s&quot;" Return="check" Execute="commit" />
```

This works fine unless the /PARAM value itself includes nested quotes, such as:

```
<CustomAction Id="PAYLOAD_EXE" FileKey="FILE2.EXE" ExeCommand="/VERYSILENT /PARAM=&quot;/s /v&quot;/qn REBOOT=ReallySuppress&quot;&quot;" Return="check" Execute="commit" />
```

Using multiple %quot; tokens does not seem to work.  Is there another way to handle this? Would it be possible to use a variable somehow to hold the string inside the "'s of the /PARAM argument? Or would it simply resolve to an unrecognizable set of quotes at compile time?

Comment: Using &quot; is the way to go to escape quotes in XML. What do you mean does not seem to work? Does the second line throw error?

Comment: Why are you using MSIs? You should look at a WiX Bootstrapper (burn) project.

Comment: The resulting MSI files would be imported by customers into a software distribution solution that understands MSI files and knows how to silently install them. The point is to simplify the work required by the customers to deploy the item to many computers. I'll take a look at the Bootstrapper as I have never used that before.

Comment: Both lines will compile; however the second line does not result in the desired behavior because it appears that the arguments being passed to FILE2.EXE simply are not recognized so it quietly does nothing. It might would work if the inner-most &quot; entities were not transformed to "'s. That's why I was wondering if a variable might be resolved at a later point and could contain &quot; entities that do not get transformed.